# How can I use Access to cross check codes between two sheets?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two sheets, WORK and County_Lookup

WORK is mailing data and will always be different.

County_Lookup is a sheet we have that is static. It has a COUNTY_CODE and a FIPS_COUNTY_CODE. It looks something like this

```
COUNTY_CODE FIPS_COUNTY_CODE
004         007
009         017
019         037
040         081
043         087
047         095
```

WORK has many mailing fields and just a COUNTY_CODE. I have appended a blank field onto the table called FIPS_COUNTY_CODE.

I want to have WORK compare its COUNTY_CODE with the County_Lookup sheet and put the value of the FIPS_COUNTY_CODE into the WORK sheet.

So for example:

If County_Lookup has this for it's data

```
COUNTY_CODE FIPS_COUNTY_CODE
004         007
```

Say WORK has 004 in its COUNTY_CODE field. It will copy the 007 into its currently blank FIPS_COUNTY_CODE field.

Comment: Please update the post with the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UPDATE` `JOIN`:

```
update work w inner join county_lookup c
on c.county_code = w.county_code
set w.fips_county_code = c.fips_county_code;
```